# Why change mat-radio-button returns reversed value?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have radio button:

```
<mat-radio-group [ngModel]="model">
    <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let d of ['a', 'b']" [value]="d" (change)="change()">
    {{ d }}
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Method is:

```
public change(): void {
   console.log(this.model);
}
```

Why when I change radio, foe example click over `a` element I get `b` element in console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've produced a working version of your code in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkadyj).

First, change `[ngModel]="model"` to `[(ngModel)]="model"`. You're currently using one-way template binding, when you need two-way template binding. The problem here is that only two-way binding will send updates from the template to your model.

See [Angular binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) for more.

Secondly, the `change()` event here runs *before* the model is updated. That's why you're seeing the old value get printed. If you start `model` with no value, then you'll notice that your original code will print `undefined` as the first output.